# Как сделать в ListView просто строки и выдвижные строки с подстроками?

Tags: android, java

Как сделать в ListView просто строки и выдвижные строки с подстроками?

```
public class NavigationActivity extends FragmentActivity {

        private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
        ImageView home;
        Fragment fragment = null;
        TextView appname;
        ExpandableListView expListView;
        HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;
        ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
        List<String> listDataHeader;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                String fontPath = "fonts/Shadow Boxing.ttf";
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation);
                home = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.home);
                home.setOnClickListener(homeOnclickListener);
                appname = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.appname);
                Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), fontPath);
                appname.setTypeface(tf);
                setUpDrawer();
        }

        /**
         *
         * Get the names and icons references to build the drawer menu...
         */
        private void setUpDrawer() {
                mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
                mDrawerLayout.setScrimColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
                mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerListener);
                expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);
                prepareListData();
                listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);
                // setting list adapter
                expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
                fragment = new MercuryFragment();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(expListView);

                expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                                switch (groupPosition) {
                                case 0:
                                        switch (childPosition) {
                                        case 0:
                                                fragment = new MercuryFragment();
                                                break;
                                        case 1:
                                                fragment = new VenusFragment();
                                                break;
                                        case 2:
                                                fragment = new EarthFragment();
                                                break;
                                        default:
                                                break;
                                        }
                                        break;

                                case 1:
                                        switch (childPosition) {
                                        case 0:
                                                fragment = new MercuryFragment();
                                                break;
                                        case 1:
                                                fragment = new VenusFragment();
                                                break;
                                        case 2:
                                                fragment = new EarthFragment();
                                                break;
                                        default:
                                                break;
                                        }
                                        break;

                                case 2:
                                        switch (childPosition) {
                                        case 0:
                                                fragment = new MercuryFragment();
                                                break;
                                        case 1:
                                                fragment = new VenusFragment();
                                                break;
                                        case 2:
                                                fragment = new EarthFragment();
                                                break;
                                        default:
                                                break;
                                        }
                                        break;

                                default:
                                        break;
                                }
                                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
                                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(expListView);
                                return false;
                        }
                });
        }

        View.OnClickListener homeOnclickListener = new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                        if(mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(expListView)){
                                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(expListView);
                        }else{
                                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(expListView);
                        }
                }
        };

        private OnItemClickListener mDrawerItemClickedListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {

                        switch(position){
                        case 0:
                                fragment = new MercuryFragment();
                                break;
                        case 1:
                                fragment = new VenusFragment();
                                break;
                        case 2:
                                fragment = new EarthFragment();
                                break;
                        default:
                                return;
                        }

                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

                        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(expListView);
                }
        };

        // Catch the events related to the drawer to arrange views according to this
        // action if necessary...
        private DrawerListener mDrawerListener = new DrawerListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDrawerStateChanged(int status) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onDrawerSlide(View view, float slideArg) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onDrawerOpened(View view) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                }
        };

        private void prepareListData() {
                listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
                listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

                // Adding child data
                listDataHeader.add("Batsman");
                listDataHeader.add("Bowler");
                listDataHeader.add("All rounder");
                listDataHeader.add("Wicket keeper");

                // Adding child data
                List<String> batsman = new ArrayList<String>();
                batsman.add("V. Kohli");
                batsman.add("G.J. Bailey");
                batsman.add("H.M. Amla");

                List<String> bowler = new ArrayList<String>();
                bowler.add("D.W. Steyn");
                bowler.add("J.M. Anderson");
                bowler.add("M.G. Johnson");

                List<String> all = new ArrayList<String>();
                all.add("R.A. Jadeja");
                all.add("Shakib Al Hasan");
                all.add("D.J. Bravo");

                List<String> wk = new ArrayList<String>();
                wk.add("A.B. de Villiers");
                wk.add("M.S. Dhoni");
                wk.add("K.C. Sangakkara");

                listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), batsman); // Header, Child data
                listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), bowler);
                listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), all);
                listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), wk);
        }

        public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

                private Context _context;
                private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
                // child data in format of header title, child title
                private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

                public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                                HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
                        this._context = context;
                        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
                        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
                }

                @Override
                public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
                        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                                        .get(childPosititon);
                }

                @Override
                public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
                        return childPosition;
                }

                @Override
                public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                                boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

                        if (convertView == null) {
                                LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                                                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                                convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
                        }

                        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                                        .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

                        txtListChild.setText(childText);
                        return convertView;
                }

                @Override
                public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
                        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                                        .size();
                }

                @Override
                public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
                        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
                }

                @Override
                public int getGroupCount() {
                        return this._listDataHeader.size();
                }

                @Override
                public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
                        return groupPosition;
                }

                @Override
                public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                                View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
                        if (convertView == null) {
                                LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                                                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                                convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
                        }

                        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                                        .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
                        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

                        return convertView;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean hasStableIds() {
                        return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
                        return true;
                }
        }
}
```

**Обновление**

Хотелось бы, чтобы в listview были как стандартные item, так и item_submenu, как вот тут:

[image]

Наведите на цель, где копать, или расскажите как! P.S. В моем коде только `item_submenu`.

Comment: Вопрос не понятен. кода слишком много. Не надо так.

Comment: Хотелось бы, чтобы в listview были как стандартные item, так и item_submenu как вот тут: http://i.stack.imgur.com/SNBAA.png.... наведите на цель, где копать или расскажите как! P.S. В моем коде только item_submenu

Comment: делайте кастомные итемы, если вы имеете в виду "стрелочку" и "троечку". Точно так же, как и для обычното ListView. А чтобы итемы были не раздвигаемыми, просто не добавляйте в них чайлдов.

Comment: Хорошо! Спасибо! Сделал! А как добавить ClickListener на нераздвигаемые item?

Comment: @sviter-pro, таки надо просто повесить слушатели на группы. Например, в методе getGroupView. Или, что лучше, задать слушатель в методе ExpListView. Что-то типа setOnGroupClickListener();

Comment: А как бы мне еще вставить сюда же разделители неподскажите?

Comment: @sviter-pro, для этого есть атрибуты "dividers" и "childDivider".

Либо можно в разметке элементов списка добавить пустой View.

Comment: Спасибо, добавил! Но я все же хотел узнать про title1 и title2 (на картинке) про эти разделители?

Comment: @sviter-pro, думаю в данном случае просто в getGroupView() по позиции элемента отдаётся другая разметка.

Comment: это как? не понимаю....